# how can I reach progressbar from different class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a progressbar in a.java class(in form).I need to reach it from b.java class .
My progressbar name is jprog.(I put it in form from palet)
How can I set public my progressbar? I cant find it in properties page.
my progressbarr in first class. But I want to change its value in second class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to your first class and using a `SwingWorker` in your second class. SwingWorker has a method called [`setProgress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) that you can invoke to set the value of your progress bar. You can then override the `propertyChange()` method in your first class and do something like this:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
      int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
      progressBar.setValue(progress);
    }
}
```

An example using a couple of classes, *ClassA* and *ClassB* can be as follows:

```
public ClassA extends JForm implements PropertyChangeListener{
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    public ClassA(){
        /**
        * Your setup for the form
        */
    }

     /**
     * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
     */
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            progressBar.setValue(progress);
        }
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        classB.execute();
    }
}

class ClassB extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        /*
         * Main task. Executed in background thread.
         */
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int progress = 0;
            //Initialize progress property.
            setProgress(0);
            //Sleep for at least one second to simulate "startup".
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 + random.nextInt(2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            while (progress < 100) {
                //Sleep for up to one second.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
                //Make random progress.
                progress += random.nextInt(10);
                setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: my progressbarr in first class. But I want to change its value in second class

Comment: @ErsinGulbahar: I updated my answer showing how you can achieve this. Note that my `ClassA` is the one that contains the `JProgressBar` whose value I want to update from another class `ClassB` depending on certain condition. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Sujay I tried use this way in my code, but the difference is that classB.execute(); will be invoked when I press a button from ClassA. The button keeps toggled until the my task finishes , at the end the progressBar goes to 100% by instantly. what is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your a class method that will update the progress bar. Then You do not have to touch directlly the progress bar.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.pleas explan that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the progressbar while your need to do it by pressing a Button  on ClassA, I still suggest the Sujay's solution, But you need to call your method using the Runnable context. It's important to avoid  performing the action within context of the Event Dispatching Thread that might block the updating of progressBar

```
public void someMethod(){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Some stuff
            classB.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            classB.execute();

        }
    });

}
```